# UNIX command line giving me apt-get errors

Tags: server, apt

I'm trying to run `apt-get update` and `apt-get install emacs23`, but I keep getting errors saying either

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix missing?
```

Running `apt-get update` gives the same result. In some cases, it will say `Unable to get some archives`. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you run `apt-get -f`? how are you connected to the internet?

Comment: I connected my computer to my router via ethernet. My other devices are connected the same way, albeit the 'nix box didn't ask for any password. Additionally, I'm kind of new to UNIX, and don't entirely understand how to connect to a network.

Comment: could you provide us the complete output ?

Comment: The output for `apt-get install emacs23` is the following:</ br>
`Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/ispell/ispell3.3.02-5_amd64.deb Could not resolve "us.archive.ubuntu.com"`</ br>
Except, this happens dozens of times, seemingly for all files.

Comment: change the server from update manager > settings > Ubuntu software > download from : to best server and try again .

Comment: I'm in command-line only mode.

Comment: This remarkably very similar to http://askubuntu.com/q/145670/32290

Comment: You can also change your download mirror by manually editing `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Answer (score 0):

> Could not resolve "us.archive.ubuntu.com"

That sounds like you don't have working Internet connectivity at all. Or at least, broken DNS.